# Making a lightsystem like Terraria?

Tags: c#, xna, lighting, light

I am trying to make my lighting similar to Terraria's, block-lighting. Now, I know how to make blocks darker, I can assign blocks to a certain lightlevel, but, how would I make an actual light entity, that emits light in a round shape (Can be diamond-shaped too)? 
Help would be greatly appreciated, also, if I wasn't clear in my question, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basic 2D lighting is very simple. Just do a distance check from your block, to your light, and use that value to scale your light.
This is something you could do fairly simple, since Spritebatch.Draw has a nice Color tint parameter [[link]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433988.aspx)

A pseudo function could be

```
distance =  (block.position - light.position). Length();
lightPower = distance / light.MaxDistance;
finalTint = light.Color * lightPower;
Render Block, with finalTint
```

For more nice looking light, you could replace "distance / light.MaxDistance" with a more smooth effect.
If you also want lights to go through a few blocks like Terraria, you could count all blocks between your block and the light source. Scale your lightPower down by that amount, and you get the same effect like Terraria has.

Of course, this is a non optimized way of doing it, but should work.

The latest Terraria version however seems to have smooth per pixel lighting instead of per block [[preview]](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6qTiBCvsv4&feature=player_embedded). For that I assume they used a second render target and/or  Pixel Shader to keep fast performance. This could be a little difficult if you are not familiar with rendering pipelines though.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Another naive way with a shader:
Drawing the scene to a rendertarget where each block is 1 pixel in the alpha channel. 
Then in a second pass do the lighting calculations and store in RGB. 
Then a third pass, for each block, take a grid of n*n, and find all the non-alpha values (a blur like algorithm?), alter the alpha to the result. And finally, merge that rendertarget back to your scene.

Of course, the rendertarget should be slightly bigger than the amount of blocks to allow for blocks that are only half in the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a game with a similar lighting model, and the way we do it is this:

1. Draw the scene, without lighting, to a render target (called the 'Scene Buffer')
2. Draw the scene's lights, represented as grayscale gradients of any required shape, to a second render target (called the 'Light Map')
3. Draw the Scene Buffer to the screen, passing in the Light Map as a parameter to the pixel shader
4. In the pixel shader, query the value of the Light Map at each pixel and adjust the color of the final pixel up or down as necessary.

This also gives you the ability to have colored lighting; all you have to do is tint the light gradients that you render to the Light Map.  Just remember to use additive alpha blending.

The downside of this approach is that it's rather naive, and provides no easy way to occlude the lights (that is to say, they pass through walls).  In our case, this isn't an issue; you might decide otherwise.

Comment: Just wondering, do you draw your textures as quads manually? (ie. not using SpriteBatch)?